# Remove the minimum number of blades

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic, puzzle

Recently, I came across this problem on [Timus online judge](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1765). For people reluctant to click on the link. The question is as follows:

> Experienced participants of the Ural Championship come to
>   Yekaterinburg in advance to get accustomed to the severe weather
>   conditions, walk around the city, and, of course, visit the “Limpopo”
>   Water Park. Not many people know that there is Plant No. 404 near the
>   water park, and this plant is called “Error 404” by the locals. The
>   plant is not easy to find indeed, and it is still more difficult to
>   learn what is happening there. Fortunately, one can watch the plant
>   from a nearby pedestrian bridge. Because of the seeming stillness and
>   desolation of the plant, one may think that it is out of operation,
>   but this is not so. The main work area of the plant is the repair of
>   aviation engines. Some time ago the plant received an order to repair
>   a broken gas turbine engine. It turned out that some blades were torn
>   off, which resulted in an excess load on the engine shaft. Experts at
>   the plant have decided that the engine could be repaired quickly by
>   removing some of the intact blades so that the center of masses of the
>   remaining blades would be on the rotation axis once again. To keep the
>   engine power as large as possible, a minimum number of blades should
>   be removed. At least one blade must be left, otherwise the engine
>   would not work at all. The experts assert that when all the blades
>   were intact their endpoints formed a regular n-gon. Tell them which
>   blades should be removed.

```
> Input The first line contains the initial number of blades in the
> turbine n and the number of torn blades k (3 ≤ n ≤ 20000; 1 ≤ k ≤ n −
> 1). The integer n has at most two distinct prime divisors. The next
> line contains k integers, which are the numbers of the torn blades in
> ascending order. The blades are numbered from 1 to n clockwise. 
Output
> In the first line output the minimum number of blades that should be
> removed. In the second line output the numbers of these blades in any
> order separated with a space. If several answers are possible, output
> any of them. If it is impossible to repair the engine by removing some
> of the blades, output “−1”. 
>
```

I am having trouble setting up this problem. My initial thought is that since the center of mass needs to be recovered, a broken blade needs to be surrounded of equal number of non-broken blades.

So if we represent a broken blade as 0 and an unbroken blade as 1, a particular configuration can be represented as:
011

I am not sure if I am on the right track and some feedback will be awesome in trying to understand this problem.

Thanks

Comment: [programmers.SE](http://programers.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for design questions.

Comment: @outis But this is more about the algorithm on how to solve this. Who "designs" a throw-away program for a little brain teaser?

Comment: @Voo: the algorithm is what needs to be designed. SO is more for implementation issues with code.

Comment: @outis The FAQ at programmers indicates that they'd like these questions as well, but questions about `a specific programming problem` or `a software algorithm` fit on SO as well. Some crossover it seems and maybe it fits better on programmers, but I don't think it's completely offtopic here.. we even have a puzzle tag after all.

Comment: @Voo: see also [What's the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/). The SO FAQ could use some updating.

Comment: @outis Interesting link, clearly supporting your point. I agree someone should update the SO FAQ to more clearly emphasize that point. As I'd interpret the SO FAQ now this kind of question would be just fine here (if not a core question, but still) while that's clearly not intended by the "higher powers".

Comment: @Voo: note that I'm not exactly saying this question doesn't belong here, but instead that programmers.SE is a better fit. It's still a transitional period while the word gets spread about programmers.SE.

Comment: Remind me never to fly on a plane repaired in "Building 404". I'm also amused by how much of the question text is tied up with describing how hard the building is to find, and where it can be observed from.

Answer (score 4):

The tips of the blades originally formed a regular `n`-gon. Visualize them as complex numbers. Without loss of generality, the radius is 1, the axis is on the origin and the tip of the blade with number `n` is on 1.

The tips of the blades are the `n`-th roots of unity, the tip of blade `k` is at

```
z_k = e^(2\pi i * k/n)
```

The center of mass after removing blades `k1, ... , kr` is on the rotation axis if and only if

```
z_k1 + z_k2 + ... + z_kr = 0
```

Now let `1 < d < n` be a divisor of `n`. The blades `k1 + m*d, 0 <= m < n/d` form the vertices of a regular `n/d`-gon. Thus removing them all leaves the center of mass on the rotation axis.

The strategy is to try to cover the list of indices of the broken blades by a set of disjoint regular `d_i`-gons, where `d_i` is a divisor of `n`. So, in the list, find pairs whose indices differ by a divisor of `n`.

Comment: -Thanks for the response. The gap in my knowledge is preventing me from fully processing your answer. I can get to the part where you represented the blades on the cartesian coordinate system as a+bi but I was somewhat lost on the remaining aspects of your explanation.I understand the points on the circumference of the circle can be represented as z_k but how's the center of mass after removing blades k1...kr turn out to be z_k1+...z_kr=0 and how does the divisors of n come into play? It will be great if you could shed some light on your intuition for laymen like myself.

Comment: **If** and only if the sum of the coordinates of the tips (or center of mass) of the removed blades is 0, then the center of mass of the remaining blades is also 0. So that's a condition we have to fulfill by removing some good blades in addition to the broken ones. Now the key point is that if `z != 1` is an `m`-th root of unity (`z^m == 1`), then the sum `1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^(m-1)` is 0. Those points form a regular `m`-gon. As an example, start with 20 blades, blades 1,2,5,14 are broken. 20 = 2^2*5 has divisors 1,2,4,5,10,20. So we must remove some sets of equally spaced blades, the ...

Comment: ... spacing being one of the divisors. Looking at the list of broken blades, we have differences of 1 (2-1), 3 (5-2), 4 (5-1), 7 (1-14), 8 (2-14), 9 (14-5). (Only differences `<= 20/2` are interesting by symmetry.) 1, 3, 7, 9 are coprime to 20, so any regular `k`-gon containing a pair with such a difference must be the full 20-gon. That leaves the differences 4 (5-1) and 8 (2-14). 8 doesn't divide 20, but 8 = 2*4. So we can cover all broken blades by the two 4-spaced pentagons 1-5-9-13-17 and 2-6-10-14-18 (and not by any smaller set).

Comment: Oops, I started out with 1,2,6,12 which would have given two squares, but found pentagons to be prettier, so changed. Unfortunately I didn't consider that without adding a fifth broken blade, the above has a solution removing fewer blades: 1-11, 2-12, 4-14, 5-15.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But I still don't see how that gives us an answer for the minimum number of blades to be removed. The whole idea of the problem seems to be maintaining symmetry after the blades have been broken. In your example we start out with 20 blades and the blades 1,2,5,14 are broken. To ensure symmetry we need to eliminate blades 19(20-19=1),18(20-18=2),15(20-15=5) and 6(20-14=6). If 20 and 10 are joined by a hypothetical line to form an axis, we need to examine the numbers between the interval 20 -> 10 and from 10 ->20, in-order to maintain the symmetry.

Comment: No, we don't need that kind of symmetry. All that is required by the problem statement is that the center of mass is on the rotation axis. In real life, a useful propeller needs a higher degree of symmetry of course, or a very small irregularity could have catastrophic consequences. But here, we are asked to remove the smallest number of blades in addition to the broken ones so that the COM is on the rotation axis, no more no less.

Comment: Thanks. The sample run in the problem has 12 blades with 3 broken blades. The broken blades are numbered 3,4 and 12. The output according to the problem, should be 2(minimum number of blades removed) and the blades to be removed are 8 and 9. I am trying to understand how to use your algorithm to get the numbers 8 and 9 from the initial configuration. From the layman's(mine) perspective 8 and 9 are the symmetrical counterparts of 3 and 4 on the face of a clock.

Comment: One opposite pair, 3-9, and one triangle, 4-8-12. The counterpart of 4 would be 10 (4 + 12/2).

Answer (score 3):

> My initial thought is that since the center of mass needs to be recovered, a broken blade needs to be surrounded of equal number of non-broken blades.

No. The propeller must be rotationally symmetric. If one blade is broken off of a 3-blade propeller, there's no way of recentering it.

The key points are:

1. > The experts assert that when all the blades were intact their endpoints formed a regular n-gon.
2. > The integer n has at most two distinct prime divisors.

Start with something simple that fits these two properties, such as a decagon. Ask yourself: how do polygons and symmetry relate? How do divisors of 10 then relate to polygons and symmetry? To simplify things, can you represent these polygons using scalars rather than two-dimensional points? Hint: modular arithmetic plays into the solution.

Pictures of blade configurations (both unfixed and fixed) should help. For example:

```
        2                     2                     2                   2           
    3       1                     1                                                 
  4           0         4           0         4           0       4           0     

  5           9         5                                 9       5           9     
    6       8             6       8             6       8                   8       
        7                     7                     7                   7           
   whole 10-gon        2 broken blades       3 broken blades     3 broken blades
```

There are two potential solutions to the 2 broken blades and first 3 broken blades, though only one is optimal for each. The second 3-broken has one solution. Look for the polygons.

Comment: -I spent some time mulling over your response and it seems like numbers with atmost two prime numbers display a rotational symmetry where the complement of the number on the polygon can be found by subtracting that number from the total number of sides. Lets say the total number is 12, with numbers 1 through 12 displayed in a clockwise manner, if the sides 3,4 and 12 are broken, their symmetrical counterparts can be found by subtracting these numbers from 12, which will be 9,8 and 0 respectively.So the blades to be eliminated are 9 and 8(like in the problem). Am I on the right track?

Comment: Also 12%9=3 and 12%8=4..which gets us back to the broken blades.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is indeed very complicated mathematically but can be simplified by a good understanding of how balancing works.

- If the number of blades "n" is a prime number, there is no solution other than removing every blade. One can't rebalance even one missing blade when n is a prime. If there is no solution for one blade, there won't be a solution for multiple missing.
- It the number of blades "n" is not a prime, by definition (and according to the rule of this problem) it is the produce of two primes "p1" and "p2", Example: for 21 blades, p1=3, p2=7.

If one blade "k1" is missing, balance will be obtained  when a total
   of "N/p2 (example=3)  blades equally spaced have been removed
   (visualize the Mercedes Benz sign).
If two blades "k1" and "k2" are
   missing, balance will be obtained by doing exactly for "k2" as the
   preceding case, EXCEPT if k1 and k2 are spaced following the "p1" or
   "p2" symmetry

Examples with 12 and 20 blade make things difficult to understand, because they are multiple of 4, which means two symmetries of an order 2. 
I prefer examples with 21 blades, which don't have this problem.

1. 21 Blades, one missing blade k1 = 1 -> Balance is obtained by removing blade 8 and 15 (Symmetry p1 is order  3)
2. 21 Blades,  two missing blades  k1=1, k2=2 ->  Balance is obtained by removing blade 8 and 15 for k1, and 8 and 16 for k2
3. 21 Blades,  two missing blades   k1=1, k2=8 -> since k2-k1=7, you just need to remove blade 15 to complete the balance
4. 21 Blades,  two missing blades   k1=1, k2=7->since k2-k1=6 = 2*3, you can remark that  the blades are on the symmetry of order 7, therefore you could complete the pattern by removing  the blades 4,10,13,16,19 to get perfect balance. But interestingly, you can also treat it as the example #2, and use two times the symmetry of order 3; so there is also a solution by removing  blade 8 and 15 to balance k1, and 14 and 21 to balance k2.

Therefore to solve your problem, your algorithm should do these things:
 -  If n is a prime, simply output "-1" - no solution
 - Starting wit the first missing blade, scan for groups of missing blade spaced by "n/p1 (= 7)" and "n/p2(=3)" . Count how many groups of each symmetry group have, and how many blades you need to replace.

- In the example, your first order solution is simply:
  The number of blades to remove will be (number of groups of symmetry p1) *7 + (Number of groups of symmetry p2 )*3 - number of blades missing.
  You'll have to treat the exceptions like the one shown in example 4 where it is better to treat blades individually, but you get the picture.